# Uploading a text box into a text file on an ftp C#

Tags: c#, file, text, upload, ftp

I am trying to stream a multiline textbox into a text file on an ftp server. Can someone tell me where I may be going wrong?

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UriBuilder b = new UriBuilder();
    b.Host = "ftp.myserver.com";
    b.UserName = "user";
    b.Password = "pass";
    b.Port = 21;
    b.Path = "/myserver.com/directories/" + selected + ".txt";
    b.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeFtp;
    Uri g = b.Uri;

    System.Net.FtpWebRequest c = (System.Net.FtpWebRequest)System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(g);
    c.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

    System.Net.FtpWebResponse d = (System.Net.FtpWebResponse)c.GetResponse();

    System.IO.Stream h = d.GetResponseStream;
    System.IO.StreamWriter SW = new System.IO.StreamWriter(h);
    String[] contents = textBox1.Lines.ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < contents.Length; i++)
    {
        SW.WriteLine(contents[i]);
    }



    h.Close();
    SW.Close();

    d.Close();
}
```

The error I am getting is this line:

System.IO.StreamWriter SW = new System.IO.StreamWriter(h);

Stream was not writable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

The *response* stream from an FTP site is data *from* the site *to* you. You'd need the *request* stream... but then you wouldn't want a method of `DownloadFile` - you're not downloading, you're uploading, so you want the `UploadFile` method.

Additionally:

- You're not closing anything if exceptions are thrown: use `using` blocks for this.
- It's a bad idea to do network access like this on the UI thread; the UI thread will block (so the whole UI will hang) while the FTP request is happening. Use a background thread instead.

Comment: When I switch to upload file I get an error with this line:

System.IO.Stream h = d.GetResponseStream;

Cannot convert method group 'GetResponseStream' to non-delegate type 'System.IO.Stream'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: I am now getting an error with this line: System.IO.StreamWriter SW = new System.IO.StreamWriter(h); Stream was not writable...

Comment: As I said in the answer, you shouldn't be opening the response stream at all - you should be opening the *request* stream.

Answer (score 5):

To upload a file you need to use the [`FtpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) class.

Quote:

> When using an FtpWebRequest object to
>   upload a file to a server, you must
>   write the file content to the request
>   stream obtained by calling the
>   [`GetRequestStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.getrequeststream.aspx) method or its
>   asynchronous counterparts, the
>   [`BeginGetRequestStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream.aspx) and
>   [`EndGetRequestStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.endgetrequeststream.aspx) methods. You must
>   write to the stream and close the
>   stream before sending the request.

For an example of uploading a file (which you can change to writing stream content as in your example) [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx).

Comment: I dont have the option to add getrequest stream - it keeps throwing me errors.

Comment: @David: "it keeps throwing me errors" isn't very precise... could you give the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.getrequeststream.aspx) and slightly modified:

```
public static bool UploadFileOnServer(string fileName, Uri serverUri)
{
    // The URI described by serverUri should use the ftp:// scheme.
    // It contains the name of the file on the server.
    // Example: ftp://contoso.com/someFile.txt. 
    // The fileName parameter identifies the file 
    // to be uploaded to the server.

    if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(fileName);
    byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
    sourceStream.Close();
    request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

    // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

    Console.WriteLine("Upload status: {0}",response.StatusDescription);

    response.Close();  
    return true;
}
```